# How to fill the borders of a widget that covers the entire MainWindow in PyQT6?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt6

I'm building an interface that uses pre-trained models to edit images. As these models take a while to respond(about 3-5 minutes), I decided to implement a loading screen so the system doesn't "freeze".

To do this, create the following LoadingWidget:

```
class LoadingWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 150);")
        self.loading_label = QLabel(self)
        self.loading_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
        self.setFixedSize(1150, 700)

        movie = QMovie('interface\\icons\\loading.gif')
        self.loading_label.setMovie(movie)
        movie.start()
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.loading_label)
```

This widget is called in my MainWindow like this:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):

        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1100, 700)
        MainWindow.setFixedSize(1150, 700)


        self.centralwidget = QWidget(parent=MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.loading_view = LoadingWidget(parent=MainWindow)
```

When I run my code, shows the LoadingWidget, what I got is a frame that covers the entire interface (as expected), however, with some free borders on the sides:

[image: the frame does not cover the sides]

Can you help me understand?

notice that i used the setFixedSize() method with the same dimensions as the MainWindow.

Comment: Use `layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)`. Note that it doesn't make a lot of sense to have a QWidget containing a single QLabel for this. Just subclass from QLabel and do `self.setMovie(movie)`. Also, calling `resize()` and then `setFixedSize()` with a different size is pointless; just do the latter.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks a lot, bro!

Comment: Finally, it seems like you're trying to edit or merge code created by pyuic, which is considered bad practice. If that's the case, please don't do it: those files are intended to be left as they are and **never** modified, unless you **really** know what you're doing (as the warning in their header clearly points out). The only proper way to use those files is to follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt6/designer.html), if you need to add custom widgets, then either add them from code, or use promoted widgets.